# Getting date ranges for multiple datetime pairs

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, datetime

Given a datetime array of the shape `(n, 2)`:

```
x = np.array([['2017-10-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-12T00:00:00.000000000']], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

`x` has shape `(1, 2)`, but in reality it could be `(n, 2)`, `n >= 1`. In each pair, the first date is always smaller than (or equal to) the second. I want to get a list of all date ranges between each pair of dates in `x`. This is what I'm doing basically:

```
np.concatenate([pd.date_range(*y, closed='right') for y in x])
```

And it works, giving

```
array(['2017-10-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-05T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-06T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-07T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-08T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-10T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-11T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-12T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

But this is pretty slow because of the list comp - it isn't exactly vectorised as I'd like. I'm wondering if there's a better way to obtain date ranges for multiple pairs of dates?

I'll provide as much clarification as needed. Thanks.

Comment: Np.arange works with datetime64  values

Comment: @hpaulj that's awesome `np.concatenate([np.arange(row[0], row[1] + 1) for row in x.astype('datetime64[D]')]).astype('datetime64[ns]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tad convoluted...
But

```
d = np.array(1, dtype='timedelta64[D]')
x = x.astype('datetime64[D]')
deltas = np.diff(x, axis=1) / d
np.concatenate([
    i + np.arange(j + 1) for i, j in zip(x[:, 0], deltas[:, 0].astype(int))
]).astype('datetime64[ns]')

array(['2017-10-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-05T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-06T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-08T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-10T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-11T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-12T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

---

**How it works**

- `d` represents one day
- `x` is turned into dates with no timestamps
- `diff` gets me the number of days difference... but in `timedelta` space
- I divide by my `d` which is also in `timedelta` space and the dimensions disappear... leaving me with `float` which I cast to `int`
- When I add the first column of the pairs `x[:, 0]` to an array of integers, I get a broadcasting of adding 1 unit of whatever the dimension is of `x`, which is `datetime64[D]`.  So I'm adding one day.

---

**Derived from / Inspired by @hpaulj**
Will remove if they post an answer

```
d = np.array(1, dtype='timedelta64[D]')
np.concatenate([np.arange(row[0], row[1] + 1, d) for row in x])

array(['2017-10-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-05T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-06T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-08T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-10T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-11T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-12T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: Wow, it's 3 times faster just for a single pair! How does it work?

Comment: I somewhat understand how these solutions work now thanks to you. I've attempted to play with them and tweak them (only a bit, not much) for my [own use case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46968547/4909087). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Although I'd wager you could find an even better solution to that answer... ;-)

Comment: Looking at it now (-: